# Inductor's back-emf vs voltage drop across resistor

Tags: induction, inductance

In almost all physics books I've seen it says that the back-emf generated across inductor causes the delay in current (current is shifted 90 degrees with respect to the voltage across inductor). I just think this is wrong. There's no difference between so-called back-efm in inductor and a simple voltage drop across resistor, meaning that if we have two circuits:

1) AC voltage source + resistor,

2) AC voltage source + inductor,

then the voltage across the resistor and inductor, respectively, will be the same with respect to the source voltage! The existence of back-emf in the first case doesn't explain why the current is lagging behind the voltage across inductor.

You can agree that considering this in terms of cause and effect is pretty pointless. The back-emf is proportional to the rate of change of final current (the current that has been already modified by that back-emf). It's like an 'egg or chicken' problem. However, the formula is really simple.

One more problem here - why I think 'back-emf' is a bad name? Because it's not a electromotive force. In a circuit like 2), the Kirchoff law says the voltage across the inductor (back emf) is exactly opposite to the source electromotive force (both added give zero). Suppose back-emf was a real emf. Then there would be no current as the net emf would be zero!

Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: The back-emf of an inductor is generated and adjusts as the current goes through the wire. This is not the same as a voltage drop across a resistor. Like the physics texts tell you, it absolutely is the cause of the current phase difference. See [this link](http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/ac_theory/ac_ccts_51.php)

Comment: My point is that in circuit 2), the voltage drop across the resistor is equal the back-emf in circuit 1), assuming identical source voltage wave. If back-emf and voltage drop is the same thing, then it doesn't explain the delay in current. Yes I know the formula, V=dI/dt*L, but that's another story. Are you telling me that by "back-emf" we also mean this formula?

Comment: the back-emf doesn't immediately manifest itself. It's a response to an imposed current, which means that it will be proportional to the way the current is changing. The voltage dropped across the inductor must be equal to the voltage supplied by the source (if alone in the circuit), which means the current must be offset in phase from that by 90 degrees, because of that derivative that represents the way the current changes and, thus, produces the back-emf

Comment: There's another issue here - the back-emf across the inductor is proportional to derivative of current AFTER the current has been changed by the inductor. That just feels weird to me. The inductor delays the current and then it 'looks at' this modified current, taking derivative of it and setting back-emf which has to be equal to source voltage (Kirchoff voltage law).

Comment: not after, *while* the current is changed by the inductor. It's a mutual thing. Happens simultaneously

Comment: You can agree that considering this in terms of cause and effect is pretty pointless. It's like an 'egg or chicken' problem. However, the formula is beautifuly simple. And yes, the back-emf is proportional to the rate of change of final current (the current that has been already modified by that back-emf). It's just what the formula says.

Comment: The current in V=dI/dt*L is the 'final' current, so to speak. So I'm either right or don't understand it at all. Just let me know please.

Comment: There is no initial and final current. There is just the current. It's like solving coupled equations simultaneously. Sure they both depend on each other, but that doesn't mean you solve one first to get the other, it means you solve both of them at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, don't mix up voltage with current.  In your examples 1 and 2 it is certainly true that the voltages across the resistor and inductor are the same w.r.t. the source voltage.  This is just Kirchhoff's voltage law.  However, this still results in a current lag in the inductor compared to the resistor.  Say the source voltage is

$\Delta V_S = V_0 \sin(\omega t)$

So the resistor voltage is

$\Delta V_R = - V_0 \sin(\omega t)$

so that $\sum \Delta V = 0$ as Kirchhoff's law requires.  The same goes for the voltage across the inductor, $\Delta V_L$.

But for the resistor we have Ohm's Law

$\Delta V_R = IR$ so the current through the resistor is just

$I_R = -\frac{V_0}{R} \sin(\omega t)$

But for the inductor we have

$\Delta V_L = - L \frac{dI}{dt}$.

So to get the current, $I_L$, you need to **integrate** $\Delta V_L$ w.r.t. time so in this example you will get a cosine instead of a sine.  Thus, we see a phase shift in the current (but not the voltage).  It is worth going through the integral yourself, but it is also in most elementary circuits textbooks.

Comment: What I meant was that the notion of 'back-emf' is just voltage drop, nothing else. It doesn't contain the formula for voltage in an inductor. However, $\Delta V_L = - L \frac{dI}{dt}$ is the property of the inductor. It's important to remember that voltage causes current.

Comment: @user4205580 voltage causes current through a closed circuit, but through an inductor it is the change in current that causes a voltage

Comment: @user4205580, I agree that the term "back-emf" is not very useful.  I don't use that term myself because as far as I'm concerned $\Delta V_L$ is a voltage just like any other.

Answer (score 0):

This question and your explanation are total nonsense...

First of all, an inductor generates reactance not resistance, which is why in the frequency domain, we have an "i" in the equation for an inductor's impedance. This is where the 90 degree phase shift comes from. This is a basic manipulation involving complex numbers. This comes from taking a Fourier transform of Faraday's law with self-inductance.

Second, the back-EMF generated across the inductor depends on the frequency of the AC signal, which is why frequency appears in the equation for the reactance of an inductor. So you can't compare what happens in a resistor (which is frequency-independent) to what happens in an inductor (which is frequency-dependent).